# SAMP with Rails and React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, saml, onelogin

I would Like to configure SAML for the SSO purpose in my current application. My application has backend with rails and frontend in ReactJs and would like to use SSO to authenticate over decobe platform. As per my research i found that SAML would help me to authenticate over docebo from my entity provider (my web application). Please help me how can i integrate SAML in above scenario.

Comment: I've personally used this gem: https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml for SAML integration. the code which you need is already given as an example and the configs like `idp_entity_id`, `idp_cert`, `idp_sso_target_url` is something you should receive from the identity provider platform, in this case docebo

Comment: Also, Don't forget to share the efforts/steps you have taken to resolve this issue, that way others can help you better.